# Deleting to the beginning of line when line starts with whitespace characters

Tags: vim

I usually use 
<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>^</kbd> to delete to the beginning of line.

But if the line starts with space or tabulations, the deletion does not go all the way to start of line.

Example:

> foo foo

The line starts with two spaces, and the cursor is between the two "foo"

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>^</kbd> deletes the first foo, but not the two spaces before it.

It is obviously useful most of the time, but what if I do want to delete everything?

Comment: `:he ^<Return>1G/first char<Return>` :)

Comment: `^` means go to first non-blank character, see http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html

Comment: is there a way to do it not in vim, but in browser for example?

Comment: what really annoys me is that if you are after the last character '<c-o>d^' will leave you with that last character. And this holds for all the answers below.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You can use `d0` to delete to the real beginning of the line.

Comment: Just noticed that `d-<Home>` combination has the same effect.

Comment: what about "Delete the entire line, and go into insert mode"?  ie, the equivalent of `0Di`?

Comment: @Jonah I think what you're looking for is `S`.

Answer (score 33):

as **@GWW** mention and:

- use `c0` to delete to real begginning of the line and go insert mode.
- `c^` - delete to first non-blank character and go insert mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `|` to goto column 0 of a line, which can be using in combination with `d` as `d|` to delete to column 0 of a line.

Source: http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/vi.html

Answer (score 1):

If the cursor in the middle of an empty space between beginning of line and the first character of the line, then you can delete the whole spaces with `diw`, that means: delete inner word. In this case word is the spaces.